# Randomizing values in specman

Tags: specman

Given 3 numbers

```
  a:  uint (bits :2);
  b : uint (bits :2);
  c:  uint (bits :2);
```

What is the way to define constraints for these numbers that satisfy the following:
- at least one of them has to be different than 0
- the product of all the non-zero numbers has to be in a certain range (e.g [3..20])

Answer (score 3):

The most elegant way to write it would be:

```
keep ((a>0?a:1) * (b>0?b:1) * (c>0?c:1)) in [3..20];
```

Note that it also enforces that at least one of the items to be different than 0, since if all are 0s then the product would be 1 and the constraint won't be satisfied.
But to make it cleared for future readers you can add:

```
keep a > 0 or b > 0 or c > 0;
```

Comment: Does the ternary operator create any kind of constraint ordering?

Answer (score 1):

You can write all of these out explicitly:

```
struct some_struct {
  a:  uint (bits :2);
  b : uint (bits :2);
  c:  uint (bits :2);

  keep a > 0 or b > 0 or c > 0;

  keep a > 0 and b > 0 and c > 0 => a * b * c in [ 3..20 ];

  keep a > 0 and b > 0 and c == 0 => a * b in [ 3..20 ];
  keep a > 0 and b == 0 and c > 0 => a * c in [ 3..20 ];
  keep a == 0 and b > 0 and c > 0 => b * c in [ 3..20 ];

  keep a == 0 and b == 0 and c > 0 => c in [ 3..20 ];
  keep a == 0 and b > 0 and c == 0 => b in [ 3..20 ];
  keep a > 0 and b == 0 and c == 0 => a in [ 3..20 ];
};
```

This is kind of a lot of code and if you need to change your range (`[ 3..20]`) you need to do it in quite a few places.

Comment: I had thought about using some intermediary list and constraint the product of its elements, but the `product()` pseudo-method isn't generative.

Comment: In fact there are some missing keep int this solution. For example the case a==0 and b==0  and c> 0 is unconstrained

Comment: @user3582035 Yeah, in those cases a, b, c will be 3. I didn't put them in for clarity, but I can add them now.